# Как организовать в css появление текста при наведении мыши на объект?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Привет всем!
Не могу решить проблему.
Допустим есть такой объект

[image: img]

(блок под ним текст (должно быть)).
Как в выделенную область (я показал стрелками) поставить текст?
[Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ2Jx/) xtml и css.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Вам поможет  [Псевдоэлемент After](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after) или [Псевдоэлемент Before](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before)
Например:

```
div:hover:after{
        content: "hi";
}
```

---

**UPD:** Ваш CSS и HTML куском - сложно отредактировать(нужен блок), но все же попробую:

```
#works li:hover:after{
    content:"hi";
    position:relative;
    top: -60px;
    left: -500px;
}
```

Comment: не понимаю как это реализовать в моем коде ...
подскажете?

Comment: ну вместо `div` будет `.content`

Comment: Спасибо. Но не это, при наведении появляется текст не на всех блоках. На некоторых сползает ...

Answer (score 0):

Сделай, следующее: 
после закрытия `<ul id="works">`
создай класс, `<div class = "text">Текст вот тут</div>`

CSS код:

```
 .text p {
 color: #404040;
 }
 .text p:hover:after{
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо. не работает к сожалению так ....

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно при наведении просто отобразить текст, то воспользуйтесь вот этим примером - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/3fzng/2/

Если необходимо сделать отображение с помощью анимации, то воспользуйтесь CSS3 или jQuery.

Comment: такой код я знаю как реализовать. я не знаю как сделать в моем примере ...

Comment: Вы как-то выделите в стилях, чтобы было видно, что вы хотите, а то в jsfiddle ничего не отображается. Обозначьте границы элементов, и подробнее опишите то, что необходимо сделать.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант! http://jsfiddle.net/Y7Zux/1/

Comment: такой код я знаю как реализовать. я не знаю как сделать в моем примере ...